# Configuring modem without wifi to connect with a router?

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a Dlink modem which I want to connect with i-ball baton wireless and broadband router. what configuration do I need to have for the modem and router to be connected and how do I make the required connections?

Comment: What's the modem model?

Comment: dlink 2730u. how can I connect it with an i ball router?

Comment: Is this your device? http://www.dlink.ir/files/cache/files_products_DSL-2730U_C1_Image_L(Back)[1331ac217828c5462ec02878e6128fe7].jpg - if yes then you don't need the other wireless you've got... If it is and you still want the I-ball then this will involve some more chomped configuration as you will have two routers on your network...

Comment: what are these chomped configuration settings?

Comment: Complex*. Two routers on your network you will need to disable the DHCP on the second router (bridged or access point mode) and give it a static IP within the range of the first router subnet but not within its DHCP range.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am simply going to assume that most if not all modems and routers connect the same. I have connected and disconnected a Motorola modem and a Belkin router quite a few times and here is how I do it.

All of your necessary cables should be two (2) power adapters and two network cables.

First, un-plug your modem from the wall outlet. Do not plug the router into an outlet yet. If you have these things on a power strip (which would be easier) turn the strip off and you can plug them in at any time; then just turn the strip on at the end when everything is plugged in.

The end of the network cable that is plugged into your computer now (assuming your computer is wired at this time) will remain there. Now, you will disconnect the other end of that same cable (which is in you modem). Plug that end into the port on the router that says something like "wired 1". Take another network cable and plug that into the router, this port should say something like "modem". Plug the router's power adapter into the wall now. Plug the other end of this cable into the modem. Plug the modem back into it's electricity source.

You should be up and running, if you have any questions, let me know!

Comment: I connect router and modem as u said. Now what are the configuration settings do i need to do in my modem and router?

Comment: You shouldn't need to configure the modem if the Internet on it already works. The modem dials in and the Internet is passed through to its ethernet socket. The router then allows all your devices to connect simultaneously

Comment: @AtulSharma I have never had to do any configuring with a modem and router. At this point, what I did was take my wireless devices; access, their wireless settings, type in the access code/password and they worked. For additional settings (using Windows XP) go into the administrator > control panel > wireless/network settings. There are a a variety of settings there.

Comment: my router doesn't connect with the internet

Comment: @L.B., My modem is working fine. But when I connect the other end the ethernet cable to the wan port of the router and another cable connecting lan port of router and pc, then i am not able to connect to the internet.
What settings do i need to do???

Comment: @AtulSharma If there is a reset button on the router use that. Other wise unplug its power source and try again (you shouldn't have to go through the rest of my sequence, just unplug and then re-plug). Also, if you have an owners manual, consult that.

Comment: I've already tried this.

Comment: @AtulSharma If you are connected to the D-link port on your computer that is as it should be.

Comment: @AtulSharma It might be a minute before I reply to any more comments because I am mentally trouble shooting :)

Comment: @L.B., Do i need to configure my modem again to allow it to share internet over the router?

Comment: @AtulSharma Try this (not OSHA approved, I am sure), keep both things plugged into the wall, disconnect all cables. Then reconnect, computer to router, router to modem.

Comment: Don't connect the I-ball to your d-link by the WAN port. It must be one of its LAN ports. Then disable the I-ball DHCP server and set the I-ball to have a reserved IP via your D-Link - use the MAC address to reserve the address.

Comment: @BigChris Okay, I think we are officially out of my league. Good luck! Hope you can get everything figured out!